# Проблема с browsersync

Tags: gulp, browsersync

Не работает `browsersync` пишет что `browsersync connected`, но при внесении изменений в проект он не выдает их.

Вот код:

```
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('server', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "src"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/*.+(scss|sass)")
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/*.+(scss|sass)", gulp.parallel("styles"))
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change",browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'server', 'styles'));
```

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста конкретней свою проблему.

Comment: не работает browsersync пишет что  browsersync connected но при внесении изменений в проект он не выдает их

Comment: `var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();`

Comment: не помогло @MaximLensky